# Erro, Loop ao pressionar ENTER com e.KeyCode

Tags: c#, teclado

Estou tentando este código:

```
   private void txtEmgSearch_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            this.btnEmgSearch.PerformClick();
        }
    }
```

O comando em si funciona normalmente, mas existe um `IF` caso o `txtEmgSearch` esteja vazio:

```
   private void btnEmgSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtEmgSearch.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Insert part#!");
            return;
        }
     ...
```

[image: Ok]

Quando o `MessageBox` aparece e eu aperto a tecla `ENTER`para dar o `OK` do PopUp o sistema considera um novo `ENTER` e entra novamente na rotina `txtEmgSearch_KeyUp`. e assim eu fico num Loop, até que eu dê click em `OK` com o Mouse.

Alguma forma de resolver isso ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que tanto o MessageBox quanto o TextBox estão respondendo ao evento. Tenta usar o evento KeyDown em vez do KeyUp.

```
private void txtEmgSearch_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
        this.btnEmgSearch.PerformClick();
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maravilha! está funcionando agora.